# Access a service running on localhost with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, localhost, pubnub

The case is quite straight forward (in my mind). The client has a native application running on his machine that produces pairs of values. What I am trying to accomplish is when this service is running and the user visits my web service I want to be able to retrieve these pairs of values with JavaScript code on the clients browser. I haven't decided because I am not sure what kind of server should create the pairs or how to grap them with JS. I have tried using [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/) to setup a channel of communication but the round trips are kind of slow.
Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I push server side events from client's localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720941/can-i-push-server-side-events-from-clients-localhost)

Comment: I know this is an ancient post but what was "slow" about PubNub. There isn't any "roundtrip" involved. Your client subscribes to a channel and the server publishes data to the channel and your clients receive the data in < 1/4 second. Curious to know how you solved this back in 2012 and if this is still something you are working on and how it has evolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access a local http server (LAMP / WAMP) for AJAX calls with javascript via the `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` addresses.

Comment: I was thinking something more minimal, like creating a tcp socket service and connecting to it with a WebSocket or something, apache is increasing the complexity of the requirements and since I am running my own app on client I think it is not necessary.

Comment: PHP 5.4 has its own built-in server, you might try that. Also, Nginx is rather lightweight.