# Can I push server side events from client's localhost?

Tags: json, html, jsonp, localhost

My intention is when the user logs in to the service to be able to send from a native app on localhost events and read it from clients JavaScript. Will it require to use JSONP instead of JSON? Since each clients localhost is different from our domain?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by localhost.  A client's localhost javascript app always runs in a different domain but so long as the javascript originated from your domain only JSON is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if serverside = localhost.

For example, when you are running Google App Engine development server on your machine during development, it is actually sending push notifications to you localhost.

You might consider also doing that using node.js http://vimeo.com/13043828